# Reversing partial function parameters sequence

Tags: f#, currying, partial-application

I want to write
`List.map (fun x -> x % 3)` into a form like `List.map ((%) 3)`.
The issue with the latter is that it translates to
`List.map (fun x -> 3 % x)` **Not what I want**.

Is it possible to write `List.map (fun x -> x % 3).` in a more succinct fashion?

**Further context**
New to F#. Find it nice to be able to write succinct expressions with partial applications.

E.g. for the logic `add 3 to each item in list` can be written just as `List.map ((+) 3)`.

However, this doesn't apply to positional sensitive ops like division and modulus.
E.g. I read `List.map ((/) 3)` as - for each item in list, divide by 3.
But the actual logic is actually mapping 3 divided each item.

```
[12; 24; 36; 48] |> List.map ((/) 3)
// expect [4; 8; 12; 16]
// actual [3/12; 3/24; 3/36; 3/48] // type discrepancy. but just an example.
```

From [JL0PD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10339675/jl0pd)'s answer, I think what I want is not possible with F# (*at the moment*).

---

#### Retrospect

What I want is not feasible due to the nature of currying/parameter positioning. E.g.

```
(/) 12 3 = 12 / 3  // left hand op and right hand op are equivalent.
// val it: bool = true
```

Comment: Interesting example of using lenses. Maybe it will allow do what you want https://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html?m=1

Comment: @JLOPD's answer is the best way and is long used both formally in Haskell and, informally, inf F# since you have to define `flip` yourself. There wont be anything else in the future. An outstanding question is as to why `flip` is not a formal part of the  language.

Comment: @MartinFreedman, Don Syme, author of F#, several times gave talk `F# code I love`. He explains many decision behind language design. As another source of "why", there's [history of F#](https://fsharp.org/history/), 58 pages of reflection on F# history, impact and design

Comment: Yup I am familiar with all that. It is just a pain to add `flip` to nearly f# project. I do agree with most of his reasoning over `<|` and not having `>|` and `<|` in one line, but `flip` solves that.

Answer (score 4):

Common workaround for functions that have *incorrect* order of parameters is `flip` function

```ml
let flip f x y = f y x
```

With this function you can write

```ml
List.map (flip (%) 3)
```

A bit less universal, but more clear is to create specialized function, like `mod`

```ml
let mod y x = x % y
List.map (mod 3)
```

But I don't think that that's increases readability and/or maintainability. I would use current version instead

Comment: I would not say it is an _incorrect_ order of arguments, just not the desired order for the case at hand. This is a common issue in functional programming hence the need for a function to reverse arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with JL0PD' answer .
One more alternative is that you can define your own operator.
i.e.

```
let (%.) x y = y % x 
[12; 24; 36; 48] |> List.map ((%.) 3)
```